# How to use both subscribe and publish at the same time in mqtt python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt, paho

I am working with a device that publishes to the topic `test/123`, where `123` is the name of the device. I need to subscribe to that topic (and processes received messages); in addition I also need to send a word to the same topic (`test/123`). The device only looks at this topic.

How can I distinguish between incoming and outgoing by content? More precisely, how to send correctly. In the `on_message` method you need to do this or you need to create another method, but then how to receive incoming messages there. From the incoming messages I need to get the name of the device and then work with it.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("/test/#")


# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
    imei = msg.topic.split('test/')[1]
    data = msg.payload.decode()
    print(imei)
    print(data)
    publish(imei)
    

def publish(imei):
    client = mqtt.Client()
    user = 'test'
    passw = '1111'
    client.username_pw_set(user,passw)
    client.connect("localhost",1883)
    
    topic = '/test/'+ imei
    client.publish(topic,'hello')
    print('SEND')
    client.disconnect()
    

client = mqtt.Client()
user = 'test'
passw = '1111'
client.username_pw_set(user,passw)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("localhost", 1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: `on_message` is passed the client; assuming you are publishing to the same broker you can just use that. Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/examples/server_rpc_math.py#L79). I'm not fully understanding your issue so perhaps take a look at the example and update your question.

Comment: @Brits my problem is that the publish method loops, and I only need to send a message to it once, when a message comes from the device, and that's it

Comment: You should not be using the same topic for the second message, this design means you have no way to determine which message is which. MQTT v5 had an option to have the broker not send message published by the client back to the client, but that won't work with the code you have here because you are using 2 clients

Comment: @hardillb, tell me how to change my code so that I can both receive and send messages in one topic. this is very important for me, but I still cannot figure out how to do it

Comment: I'm saying that design is broken, and you need to come up with something different.

Comment: @hardillb, is it generally possible to implement using mqtt or not? what design are you talking about? about my code or about the capabilities of the library, I don't understand

Comment: I'm saying using the same topic like this is an inherently broken design.

Comment: You say you need to "send a word" to the topic; if the content of the messages you are sending varies from that you are receiving from the device then you can probably just filter based upon the message body (this is far from ideal but may be an option). As @hardillb comments based on the info you have provided the design appears broken (but without more detailed info its difficult to comment further).

Answer (score 2):

MQTT does not differentiate between clients in any way, that means if a client subscribes to a given topic it will receive ALL messages on that topic, including the ones it publishes it's self. So with your current design you will always get the message you publish in response to the first message back and this will trigger re-sending that message.

MQTT messages do NOT contain any information about who published the message unless you choose to add it to the payload, so you have no way to identify the incoming message as being the one you just published and this will cause a message loop storm.

The CORRECT solution is to not use the same topic for the 2 messages.

MQTT v5 has a flag that can be passed as part of establishing the connection
which prevents messages being returned to the client that published them. At this time it does not appear that the Paho Python library has a way to set this flag.

If you are using MQTT v3.1.1 and the mosquitto or RSMB MQTT broker then there is an undocumented option (this is not part of the MQTT spec) that can be set which will also prevent messages being returned. The following code will ONLY work with the 2 brokers I have mentioned.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("test/#")


# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
    imei = msg.topic.split('test/')[1]
    data = msg.payload.decode()
    print(imei)
    print(data)
    publish(client, imei)
    

def publish(client,imei):
    topic = 'test/'+ imei
    client.publish(topic,'hello')
    print('SEND')
    

client = mqtt.Client()
user = 'test'
passw = '1111'
client.username_pw_set(user,passw)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.enable_bridge_mode()

client.connect("localhost", 1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

p.s. do not start topics with a leading `/` while legal according to the spec, it will break things like shared subscriptions and adds an extra null to the start of the topic tree.

Comment: please explain what you are responsible for ```client.enable_bridge_mode()```

Comment: The entire paragraph before the code snippet explains it.

Comment: Please tell me if  need to configure something with the bridge mode when using enable_bridge_mode in the mosquitto config?